# Got no internet connection on my Ubuntu 23.04. Need help

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp

My Ubuntu had internet connection previously , but once I have set up my DNS and DHCP servers, my Ubuntu has no more internet connection.

May I know what is the main cause of not having internet connection?

Does my in real life IP address affects it or could it be some configurations that I have made during the set up of my DNS and DHCP server?

Comment: We need more detail of the problem.  With no DHCP, you get no ip assigned, with no DNS ping google.com fails, with no internet ping 8.8.8.8 fails.

Comment: "*I have set up my DNS and DHCP servers*" That seems like the main cause of the problem. But you did not need us to tell you that. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1479596/edit) to clearly explain, step-by-step, what you installed and how you configured it.

Comment: What exactly did you change? Where? What? How? And what is the output of `ip a` and `resolvectl status` and `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`? Please update/edit question with this info.